# When a correct answer isn't a useful answer

Tags: discussion, answers

While reviewing Late Answers, I came across this answer [Get the current month number in SQL Server, 1 for january, 12 for december](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465328/get-the-current-month-number-in-sql-server-1-for-january-12-for-december/26568968#26568968), which is 11 lines of SQL code (and quite complex).

The accepted answer is: `SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())`

Lets say this answer is correct (honestly, I haven't tested the code). Is this a useful answer?

I'm very aware that the same problem can have innumerous solutions, but can we consider this a solution?

I've flagged the answer as *not an answer* and it was declined (I'm not complaining!).

<sub>(I've noticed the user entered the same exact answer in two questions, so I assume a) The questions are duplicate OR b) this seems like spam / excessive promotion, but for the sake of this argument lets not focus on this).</sub>

Comment: Is it an answer, or is it a good/bad answer?  How do we generally acknowledge post quality?  Looks like you got the spam thing wrong too.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would say it's not a good answer. I believe a good answer must have a description of what the issue was and how this answer solves that issue. Besides that the posted code _should_ be the most effective. I don't think anyone will choose this answer in favor of the others.

Comment: And what do we do with answers that are not good answers?

Comment: Well, this seems like kinder garden :) I say delete them.

Comment: Bzzt.  Downvote them.  Deletion is for things like spam, gibberish, and comments posted as answers.

Comment: I've downvoted. I don't see the usefulness of keeping the answer but I assume I am being overzealous here.

Comment: Down voting is appropriate for bad answers, and I think you feel the answer is too short to be useful.  However it seems the OP found it useful enough to Accept, and reasonably so.

Comment: @hardmath I think you've misread the question. The accepted and short answer is a good one. The 11-line SQL answer is the issue here.

Comment: You have the same situation on a `vbNet` [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554026/getting-one-word-from-given-string) asked this week about String extraction. The _accepted answer_ is a code that compile, but doesn't solves the issue the OP addressed. My answer (edited after I asked clarifications from OP - and wasn't the only one to ask) is a compiling code and solves the issue, but requires the use of a List(Of String) variable. Okay, seems I was severe when asking for clarifications, but I did propose a working solution. Others left him alone soon enough.

Comment: @milz : It would be usefull to be able to Downvote or Flag an answer _without immediately loosing reputation_ if **it doesn't answer the posted question**. But this would require reviews from granted users/moderators, then either they undo the answer acceptation, either they invalidate the downvoting and flagging (with consequences for "downvoters" and "flaggers") Not really practical, so I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to each reader when evaluating a post to determine if they think that it is helpful.  There are tons of factors that should go into determining if an answer is in fact helpful.  Being technically correct is one of them, how clearly and effectively it conveys that information to the reader is another, as is its scope (what details are or are not included; is the answer lacking important information or including lots of unimportant/superfluous information).  When voting these, and many other, considerations need to be looked at, in the context of that specific post, to determine how useful you feel the answer is.

After you have personally determined whether or not you think the post is useful, you can vote accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

I think it depends on what the person asking the question wanted.
There are some questions where the person asking the question is just looking for code that will solve his problem (or the question itself is a very technical question), in which case an answer which is a block of code usually could be enough, although commenting is prefferable.

Yet there are some questions which from the question itself you can see that the person asking the question is looking for an ellaborated answer in which a block of code should obviouslly be downvoted.

That being said, I think StackOverflow isn't meant to be an answer site for a specific question of a specific user therefore, even if the person asking the question wanted a block of code as an answer, I understand downvoting an answer which is just a block of code in certain cases.

Comment: It's kind of funny that so many here get very angry if a question isn't full of supporting documentation, as they think that a poster should do a lot of research before asking.  Well, why should the initiative to research *stop* at the asking?  If a concise, effective answer prompts someone to do a little reading and learn something on their own, how is that a bad thing?  Don't assume that a brief answer is a bad one, even when the poster wants it all spelled out for them.